# User being banned

Tags: database, database-design

I've seen this a lot on forums, or having a membership somewhere, so my question since a user can be banned by admin which depends on the situation. This situation might be like not returning the item or he did not follow  the forum rules, or there is a situation where the forum or a shop does not need his service anymore. So obviously you can be banned forever or it can be temporary, where also this can be changed by admin. Would I have to make a new table ? since the ban can be more than one type and it can be changed my admin, how would I make a table ? not sure how to have an attribute for different types of bans...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a field 'statusId' in the User table, and have all the possible statuses listed in a UserStatus table. No need for user_ID in the Userstatus table.

You could then use simple join queries to retrieve the status of a user, or a list of banned users, etc.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: you mean delete user_ID in the UserStatus table and have status_ID in User table and have that a PK in the UserStatus ?

Comment: Yep, spot on. Otherwise having User_ID in Userstatus table means each row in that table will be tied to a single user.